# Make Window1 disappear and launch another Window

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have 2 Windows in my sample App (learning .Net 4 WPF)

In the first window, I have a timer and when 5 seconds passed, i want to close the current Window and open a new Window.

The problem I'm running into is closing the first window

Here's some sample code

```
MainWindow m = new MainWindow();
m.ShowDialog();
this.Hide();
```

this.Hide never actually hides the current window. I end up with 2 windows on my screen instead of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the remarks of [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) it says `When this method is called, the code following it is not executed until after the dialog box is closed.`

So, you can just swap the order of `ShowDialog` and `Hide`. and you have to use 'Show' or 'Close' after 'ShowDialog' to either display back first form or close it.

Also, note that [closing a form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx) (what you said want to do) is different to [hiding a form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.hide.aspx) (what you're currently doing).

Answer (score 1):

```
MainWindow m = new MainWindow();
this.Hide();
m.ShowDialog();
```